# hello, i want to print my list, where is it a User class object. can anoyone help me?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
   //i have User class, with userID and UserFullName
   User user1 =new User(1,"ika Jogl");
   User user2 =new User(2,"Galan Tadze");
   User user3 =new User(3,"Il Chavdze");

   userList.add(user1);
   userList.add(user2);
   userList.add(user3);//how to print this array?
```

hello, i want to print my list, where is it a User class object. can anoyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you look into overriding the ```toString()``` method and then iterating over your array to print each user?

Comment: can you write me a code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First you should try it by yourself. If it doesn't works, show us your code and tell us what problems/errors you get.

Comment: @RezoJoglidze no. That's not how SO works. We also don't know anything of your code in User.

Comment: thanks a lot. i will try myself,

Comment: Override the method `Object#toString()` in your `User` class like this : `@Override public String toString() { return "id : "+this.id+" name : "+this.name; }` and iterate on your list to print your users `userList.forEach(System.out::println);`.

Comment: Also include the code of `User` class. we need to know that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a linked arraylist:
`List<User> userList = new ArrayList();`

You can use a lambda expression to output your list:-

```
IntStream.range(0, userList.size()).forEach(m -> System.out.println("Username: " userList.get(m).UserFullName);
```